# How may I make circular thumbnails using the paperclip gem?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip, thumbnails

The new Basecamp is doing it, as it can be seen in [this link](http://37signals.com/svn/posts/3104-behind-the-scenes-reinventing-our-default-profile-pictures). I wonder how can achieve this in my rails 3 application.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See [this forum post on using masks with Imagemagick to get a circle effect](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=15492&p=54769&hilit=circle%20mask#p54769).

However, realize that in the "new basecamp" with the "circular avatars," they use simple css, not image processing. Take a look at the properties `border-radius`, `-moz-border-radius`, `-webkit-border-radius`, and `-khtml-border-radius`.

To do this with CSS, [take a look at this gist](https://gist.github.com/1505123) or [this blog post](http://bryanhadaway.com/how-to-create-circles-with-css/).

Comment: And CSS is The Right Thing (TM) in that case, because it is the most flexible solution.

Answer (score 2):

I have no experience using Rails, but from what I have read [here](http://craiccomputing.blogspot.de/2010/05/rails-paperclip-and-imagemagick.html), it looks like Paperclip is using Imagemagick as its backend. So you will need to use [masking with Imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/compose/#mask).

Edit: You can follow this example and adjust the values for the circle radius:
http://loo.no/2009/08/09/rounded-corners-with-paperclip

Comment: Heads up, the link in your edit seems to be an empty page now :(